# Batch File - If File Drive Letter Equals W then

Tags: batch-file

I have what I believe should be an easy answer to a question but I am having a difficult time figuring out the coding for it.

I have a batch file that runs when single or multiple files are sent through the SEND TO command when right clicking.

What I would like is if the file(s) are coming or located on a specific drive letter then it will go to a dialog and end.

I just need help figuring out the drive letter part...

if "file directory letter" = W: goto :errordialog

I have tried:

```
if %cd%=="W:\" goto :errordialog
if %~d1=="W:\" goto :errordialog
```

I have tried other codes but I think I have to do it another way?

I know I have to be making this too hard right?

Comment: Well what seemed to work is :   [%~d1]==[W:]

Answer (score 2):

Well what seemed to work is :

```
[%~d1]==[W:]
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer, but this is safer:

```
if "%~d1"=="W:"
```

The quotes(`"`) makes the string as one piece. So this wouldn't happen:

```
if [ ]==[W:]
```

Although this shouldn't happen when `%1` is a path, just a pre-caution.